# pandas assert error for empty column

Tags: python

I have a list that when populated, will be put into a `pandas dataframe`. Sometimes, the `main_list` has `4` elements in each `list`, sometimes it has `3`.

```
# Example list 1
[["foo1", "baa1", "faa1", "gaa1"], ["foo2", "baa2", "faa2", "gaa2"], ["foo3", "baa3", "faa3", "gaa3"]]

# Example list 2
[["foo1", "baa1", "faa1"], ["foo2", "baa2", "faa2"], ["foo3", "baa3", "faa3", "gaa3"]]
```

I define my pandas dataframe columns when I read the `main_list` into it. I don't seem to have an issue executing the below code for `example list 1 and 2`.

```
pandas.Dataframe(example_list, columns={"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"})
```

My issue comes in when sometimes, on special occasions, `example list 3` comes about

```
# Example list 3
[["foo1", "baa1", "faa1"], ["foo2", "baa2", "faa2"], ["foo3", "baa3", "faa3"]]
```

When this happens, there are only `3` elements in the list instead of the usual `4`. Pandas will then throw me an `AssertionError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns`

I understand what is happening, that because there are only `3` elements. But what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a generic DataFrame first (without specifying the column names), and then rename the columns after-the-fact:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(example_list)
df.columns = columns[:len(df.columns)]
df = df.reindex(columns=columns)
```

When `example_list` is your third example, `pd.DataFrame(example_list)` will only have 3 columns. To ensure `df` has all four columns, use `reindex`. This is the purpose of the last line above.

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

A = [["foo1", "baa1", "faa1", "gaa1"], ["foo2", "baa2", "faa2", "gaa2"], ["foo3", "baa3", "faa3", "gaa3"]]

B = [["foo1", "baa1", "faa1"], ["foo2", "baa2", "faa2"], ["foo3", "baa3", "faa3", "gaa3"]]

C = [["foo1", "baa1", "faa1"], ["foo2", "baa2", "faa2"], ["foo3", "baa3", "faa3"]]

columns = "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"

for example_list in (A, B, C):
    df = pd.DataFrame(example_list)
    df.columns = columns[:len(df.columns)]
    df = df.reindex(columns=columns)
    print(df)
```

yields

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  foo1  baa1  faa1  gaa1
1  foo2  baa2  faa2  gaa2
2  foo3  baa3  faa3  gaa3
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  foo1  baa1  faa1  None
1  foo2  baa2  faa2  None
2  foo3  baa3  faa3  gaa3
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  foo1  baa1  faa1   NaN
1  foo2  baa2  faa2   NaN
2  foo3  baa3  faa3   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do to have a generic solution, using pandas [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
column_names = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]

def max_elements(nested_lst):
   return max([len(lst) for lst in nested_lst])    

pandas.DataFrame(example_list, 
                 columns=column_names[:max_elements(example_list)]).reindex(columns = column_names)
```

This is my output with your latest list:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0  foo1  baa1  faa1   NaN
1  foo2  baa2  faa2   NaN
2  foo3  baa3  faa3   NaN
```

Comment: Hmm, would it be possible do something like `fillna` for the empty column instead?

Comment: Sure, which value do you want to fill the column with? You can use the fill_value argument of reindex

Comment: No I mean like, keep that `4 column_names`, but fill the empty column with NAN or something. Would that be possible? I am inclined to keep `4 column_names` because the codes later on makes use of it.

Comment: I do keep 4 columns, with the fourth filled with NaNs (reindex is doing that). Am I missing something?

Comment: No it works good! I tried it myself too. :) Thanks for this. I accepted unutbu's answer because I felt that it seems easier.